# Error in deploying django app on Google cloud "google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project "

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, django-settings

I am trying to deploy my own django app on google cloud.
I'm following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#gcloud_3)
by Google Cloud to deploy the app.
I have changed the settings.py file of my app according to the settings.py file of settings.py file of the sample app provided by google and I think this issue is due to some mistake in that setting file or maybe something else. I'm not able to solve the error after lots of attempts.
please help me thank you

**Settings.py file**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import io
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import environ
from google.cloud import secretmanager

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# [START gaestd_py_django_secret_config]
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

if os.path.isfile(env_file):
    # Use a local secret file, if provided

    env.read_env(env_file)
# [START_EXCLUDE]
elif os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    # Create local settings if running with CI, for unit testing

    placeholder = (
        f"SECRET_KEY=a\n"
        f"DATABASE_URL=sqlite://{os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')}"
    )
    env.read_env(io.StringIO(placeholder))
# [END_EXCLUDE]
elif os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", None):
    # Pull secrets from Secret Manager
    project_id = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    settings_name = os.environ.get("SETTINGS_NAME", "django_settings")
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{settings_name}/versions/latest"
    payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

    env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
else:
    raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")
# [END gaestd_py_django_secret_config]



SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env("DEBUG")

# [START gaestd_py_django_csrf]
# SECURITY WARNING: It's recommended that you use this when
# running in production. The URL will be known once you first deploy
# to App Engine. This code takes the URL and converts it to both these settings formats.
APPENGINE_URL = env("APPENGINE_URL", default=None)
if APPENGINE_URL:
    # Ensure a scheme is present in the URL before it's processed.
    if not urlparse(APPENGINE_URL).scheme:
        APPENGINE_URL = f"https://{APPENGINE_URL}"

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [urlparse(APPENGINE_URL).netloc]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [APPENGINE_URL]
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
# [END gaestd_py_django_csrf]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'portpolio.apps.PortpolioConfig',
    'CRblogs.apps.CrblogsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_social_share',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crrathod.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':  [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crrathod.wsgi.application'


# Database
# [START db_setup]
# [START gaestd_py_django_database_config]
# Use django-environ to parse the connection string
DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}

# If the flag as been set, configure to use proxy
if os.getenv("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY", None):
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 8088

# [END gaestd_py_django_database_config]
# [END db_setup]

# Use a in-memory sqlite3 database when testing in CI systems
# TODO(glasnt) CHECK IF THIS IS REQUIRED because we're setting a val above
if os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

# STATICFILES_DIRS =[
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# ]

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**Log file**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 72, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Permission denied on resource project  my-portfolio-361305."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1662731782.139000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[2404:6800:4009:825::200a]:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":967,"grpc_message":"Permission denied on resource project  my-portfolio-361305.","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\LONAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\crrathod\settings.py", line 50, in <module>
    payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\secretmanager_v1\services\secret_manager_service\client.py", line 1440, in access_secret_version
    response = rpc(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 74, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project  my-portfolio-361305. [links {
  description: "Google developer console API key"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com/project/ my-portfolio-361305/apiui/credential"
}
, reason: "CONSUMER_INVALID"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "secretmanager.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "consumer"
  value: "projects/ my-portfolio-361305"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just shifted from one problem to another. I did some changes here. I have removed space after = from this cmd `set GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=my-portfolio-361305` previously I was using `set GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT= my-portfolio-361305` this cmd. Now I have also removed space after = in secret manager file as I read that in some solutions for my new problem [Error in deploying Django app on Google cloud using appengine "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73665524/error-in-deploying-django-app-on-google-cloud-using-appengine-django-core-excep).

I got a solution to that problem as well by running `set SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key_value`

But now got a new problem as after running `python manage.py makemigrations`
as

> RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for >database connection 'default': connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432>failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "CRRathod"
>
> warnings.warn(
> No changes detected

It seems here as I have entered the wrong password. But I check that as well

Thank You!